# set global environment variable in setlocal environment

Tags: batch-file

I am wondering if anyone can help me in here... I have following problem with my bat-file:

script.bat:

```
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set variable=false
call :continue script2.bat
echo variable in script: %variable%
exit B /0

:continue
set batScript=%1
call %batScript%
call :error_but_continue
echo variable in continue: %variable%
exit /B 0

:error_but_continue
EndLocal & set variable=true
echo variable in error_but_continue: %variable%
exit /B 1
```

I know that script now looks a bit strange, that's just because it's a tiny snippet of the full big image.

My output now is as follows:

```
variable in error_but_continue: true
variable in continue: true
variable in script: false
```

Why is the value in the script itself not set to "true" now? How is it possible to change without having to remove the overall "Setlocal" in the beginning of the script?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why are you using `EnableDelayedExpansion` then seemingly using `EndLocal` to effectively disable it again? You may need to expand a little on your task and both script contents in order for us to advise on the most appropriate fix.

Comment: Well, the big idea is as follows:
I have one script calling several small ones one after another - and in case one of the small ones fails I want to send a signal to another "parent" script (not the errorlevel, this is handled separately). Each script represents a phase of an upgrade - and in case a phase is running into an error I want to differ between "continue on error" or "cancel on error". So even if all phase complete and one in between had an error I want to carry out the "one phase failed" in a variable back to the parent script. I know, that sounds complicated...

Comment: I do not want to remove the setlocal as there are many many other variables and settings I do not want to hand out to the parent but want them to be vanished when the whole upgrade has completed.

Comment: You try to use `endlocal` in `:error_but_continue`, but that doesn't work, because the `endlocal` has to be in the same `CALL` level like the `SETLOCAL`. Beside that rule, there is a solution with [Exception Handling with batch using erroneous GOTO](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6497)

Comment: I asked for the reason why you were enabling delayed expansion, as none of the code, _from the snippet you've provided_, needs to utilise it, but some of it may be affected by its inclusion.

Comment: What is `script2.bat`?

Comment: Every `setlocal` localisation is implicitly terminated by `exit /B`, `goto :EOF` or reaching the end of a script, which leads to the nice fact that such localisations are always limited to the `call` level they are used in, so an explicit `endlocal` is only necessary to terminate it in the same level. In contrast to that, just to mention, `pushd`/`popd` do not care about any `call` levels, any stored directory is still available when a batch script finished executing...